WD NAS Raid 5 Issues
i have an WD NAS PR4100 here, with issues in Raid 5.
It has 4 drives, and Drive 4 was broken recently.
Drive 4 has been replaced, but it is not completly sure, if the rebuild of Disk 4 was successfully.
Now drive 3 has issues, and is marked to be replaced.
I have logged into the NAS per SSH, to look for log files and to check the state of mdadm.
I cannot access the existing files on the NAS, but could maybe an Permission Issue. If i look per ls command, the files are shown. Disk 4 shows as "spare" in mdadm.
Attached the commands i used.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Please post your data as text, not image.

If you solved this, please post the actual solution as an answer, so as to help others having the same issue.
